# After upgrade to lollipop, LG D415 grays out "Enable USB Debugging" when phone is connected to PC

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-debugging

I've linked this phone to the same PC many times, but since upgrading to lollipop (5.0.2), my phone is not recognized (in adb devices) when I connect.

When I look in "Developer Options", "USB Debugging" is ungrayed when I'm not connected to my PC, and I can toggle it, but when I connect to the PC, it changes to gray.  It changes to gray whether it was enabled or not before connecting.

If I choose MTP as my connect type, I do see my phone's file system from my PC, but there's still no "USB Debugging" link.

Trying to follow the directions on http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html to connect a driver to this device, when the phone is connected, I don't see "Other Devices" in the list under "Device Manager".

My PC is running Windows 7.  My carrier (who pushed the upgrade to lollipop) is T-Mobile.

I've already tried:
 - updating all the software in SDK manager.
 - installing a driver from the phone's "pc software".
 - downloading and installing a driver.

This also fails in the same way from one other PC we have at our company that is used to set up very many other phones.

Answer (score 1):

I had to connect as a camera (i.e. pick "PTP" from the item in the drop-down menu option you get when a phone is connected) to get the device to show up in Device Manager (it showed up near the top under Android Devices).  From that point, it was standard: right click on the entry under Android Devices, select "Update Driver Software", click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer", then pick "Android ADB Interface" under "Google, Inc." as the manufacturer.

I had previously tried (several times) connecting charge-only and "MTP" and the device didn't show up under Device Manager.  It looks like I always need to connect as PTP; MTP and "debug only" still leave my device invisible to adb devices.